# Alter tables in a schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I am trying to set a default value to a column(Inserted_time), but first i need to check if the column exists in the tables. If the column doesn't exist, I need to add that column and give it a default value.
I am working with Sql Server Management Studio.
So far I have written this code:

```
IF EXISTS ( select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_CATALOG = 'DB_COPY' and COLUMN_NAME = 'Inserted_Time')
    begin
    ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT [Inserted_Time_Def] SET DEFAULT (sysdatetimeoffset()) FOR [Inserted_Time]
    end

    else

    ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN [Inserted_Time] CONSTRAINT [Inserted_Time_Def] DEFAULT (sysdatetimeoffset()) WITH VALUES
```

Once I retrieve the tables that has the column, I need to add that table_name to the Alter command. But I am not able to do that. Can someone please tell me how to use the table_names retrieved from select statement in the alter statement?

Comment: So you want to do this dynamically, and for every table? What if the column already has the constraint?

Comment: The columns doesn't have that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to put all the table names in a temporary table so you can loop through it.

After, you can use a cursor to execute a command for each table name.

In my example, I only printed the command I wanted to execute. That way you can be sure the code will do what you want first.

Example :

```
select TABLE_NAME As TableName INTO #TablesList from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_CATALOG = 'DB_COPY' and COLUMN_NAME = 'Inserted_Time'

DECLARE @TablesCursor as CURSOR;
DECLARE @TableName as NVARCHAR(max);

DECLARE @CommandToExecute as NVARCHAR(max);

SET @TablesCursor = CURSOR FOR SELECT TableName FROM #TablesList;

OPEN @TablesCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @TablesCursor INTO @TableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

 SET @CommandToExecute = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + ' WHAT YOU WANNA DO '
 PRINT @CommandToExecute
 --EXEC(@CommandToExecute)

 FETCH NEXT FROM @TablesCursor INTO @TableName;

END

CLOSE @TablesCursor;
DEALLOCATE @TablesCursor;
```

Comment: This looks great, but the EXEC(@CommandToExecute) gives the following error:

Comment: What did you modify the line before the EXEC to?

Comment: I changed the SET CommandToExecute to this  = 'Select top (2) * from ' + @TableName + ';'

Comment: What is the error you're getting? It's working on my side

Comment: I am not getting an error but I am not getting any output also. It just says 0 rows affected. Shouldn't it display the result of select statement?

Comment: Are you sure your SELECT without the "INTO #TablesList" is returning data?

Comment: I made a logical error there, I have corrected it. Thank you for your help. It worked !!

Comment: Excellent, you can upvote the answer in that case. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* that every table is in a different schema, then you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                                           WHERE T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                             AND T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                             AND C.COLUMN_NAME = N'Inserted_Time') THEN N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_SCHEMA) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_NAME) + N' ADD CONSTRAINT [Inserted_Time_Def] DEFAULT (sysdatetimeoffset()) FOR [Inserted_Time];'
                                                                                   ELSE N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_SCHEMA) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_NAME) + N' ADD COLUMN [Inserted_Time] CONSTRAINT [Inserted_Time_Def] DEFAULT (sysdatetimeoffset());'
                        END
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
                  WHERE T.TABLE_CATALOG = N'DB_COPY'
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'');

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend. If more than 4,000 characters, use SELECT

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

This will very likely hugely out perform a `CURSOR` solution if you have a large number of schemas.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can use select to print @SQL ? The output has more than 4000 characters.

Comment: @Larna : my purpose here is to learn, so it's okay if I don't know a thing or two. I think what's more important is that I am willing to learn rather than give up just because I am finding something difficult. Anyway, thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: You just need to replace `PRINT` and `SELECT` @Jenna ... Selecting the value of variable just like selecting that of a column or a function, or expression. (Also, it's a u at the end, not an a :) )